# error: expected unqualified-id before 'friend'

Tags: c++

```
struct side {           /* Attacks */
    byte attack[64];
    int king;
    byte pawns[10];
};

   static struct side white, black, *friend, *enemy;
```

This is part of a small chess program I'm doing in C++

When I compile, however, I get the following errors:

> expected unqualified-id before 'friend'
>
> expected initializer before 'friend'

Is the syntax wrong?

Comment: Are you *sure* you are writing in C++? With the exception of '`byte`', this code will compile with a **C** compiler.

Answer (score 2):

`friend` is a keyword in C++, the keyword to allow access of private members to an external object or function. You cannot use `friend` as an identifier; name it some other way (perhaps `friend_`).

Answer (score 1):

`friend` is a keyword in C++, so it cannot be used as variable name. SO's syntax highlighting makes this pretty obvious; all you can do is to pick another name.

Comment: Arghhhh! Why is comma abuse so prevalent on SO? It's driving me mad! LERN2SEMICOLONPLZKTHX

Comment: I thank you for the hint even though I find the form not very appropriate ;-/

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that; I can't imagine why.

Answer (score 0):

`friend` is a reserved keyword in c++; name it something else.

For more info about what `friend` is used for, see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/).

Answer (score 0):

`friend` is a keyword in C++. You may not use it as a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Naturally. friend is one of [**many**](http://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/) reserved keywords in c++. Just change the name